# $K[X,Y]/(XY-1)$ not isomorphic to $K[T]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Why is $K[X,Y]/(XY-1)$ not isomorphic to $K[T]?$

As a hint I should think about units. But I don't get a helpful idea.